How to gracefully terminate a process in C++?
By "gracefully" I mean: "Call local/static objects dtor before terminating without generating coredump".
I tried:

std::exit() (terminates with coredump)
std::_Exit()
std::abort() (terminates with coredump)
std::raise(SIGKILL)
std::terminate() (terminates with coredump)

They all terminate the process immediately without calling local/static objects dtor. My problem is: In my code base, I have some errors that can't be tolerated and the process should be terminated; but, also I have some global/local objects(e.g. loggers) that need dtor to be called before termination.



 Compiler: Clang 12 
 OS: Linux 5.10.0-1
 Arch: Aarch64 



std::exit "...Causes normal program termination to occur...." If you get a coredump this would suggest there are issues destroying  static obects.

Throw an exception that only main can catch.

Have you ever heard of the "static initialization fiasco"? If not look it up, but in general just try to not use global variables, and certainly do not to make them dependent on each other. Alternatives are dependency injection and an indermediate step is use "meyer's singletons"

@RichardCritten: But here: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#4 it says it could be UB and it is, I tested, and non of my dtors called before termination.

The most graceful way would be to get your program to break out of whatever event loop it is in, so that main() can return naturally.  That will allow all stack-objects' destructors to run first, and then all static/global object destructors to run.  (Be sure to join() any spawned threads before cleaning up their resources too)

@PepijnKramer: I'm sorry but that isn't how real-life commercial code-bases work. We can't be perfect in all ways.

Then just throw a unique exception ie not derived from std::exception or used anywhere else in the code base.  Put a try/catch block around main for this exception and ignore it.

@GhasemRamezani Haha I know. I have experience as an architect overseeing millions of lines of code. Refactoring to dependency injection can avoid SO much trouble and increase unit testability to boot. Once you done that you don't ever want to go back. For me this is more about "does your organization" want quality or not.

@GhasemRamezani you can rewrite your code to be less imperfect, however.  Keep doing that whenever you detect a flaw, and eventually it will become closer to perfect.

@JeremyFriesner Good point, it doesn't have to be a big bang refactoring (in fact that would not be recommended)

@GhasemRamezani std::exit is only UB per your reference if you call it during the destruction of a static storage duration object, i.e. after main has already returned.

If you want local variables to be destroyed correctly, then your only solutions are to return back through the call stack, up to and including main, or to throw an exception that you catch in main to then return from it.
However, the behavior you state for different library calls in your question is not correct, specifically std::exit() exits normally. A core dump should not be produced and although it doesn't destroy variables with automatic storage duration, it will call the destructors of static storage duration objects.
std::_Exit also exits normally, but contrary to std::exit doesn't do any clean up (not static storage duration objects or std::at_exit/std::at_quick_exit handlers either).
The other three calls cause abnormal program termination, which doesn't seem what you want.
std::raise(SIGKILL) inheriently doesn't perform any kind of clean-up. It just raises SIGKILL. The exact behavior will be OS-dependent. At least for Linux it will immediately cause the kernel to terminate the process without it ever being able to regain control.
std::terminate() will call the (possibly user-provided) terminate handler. The default terminate handler calls std::abort.
std::abort causes the SIGABRT signal to be raised without any clean-up (just like std::_Exit, but abnormally). The signal might be caught or end up with the process being killed immediately if not.
None of them perform stack unwinding to destroy local variables with automatic storage duration.

Call exit() function with the right error code passed as parameter. Specify 0 for a normal termination and any value greater than 0 to specify an error. A common mistake is to pass a negative value which is misinterpreted by reaper programs like systemd which will believe that the process terminated because of a signal receipt.
Moreover, for additional cleanups, you can register callback functions through atexit() to be called upon exit.
